# Use zlib.js to decompress python zlib compress

Tags: javascript, python, zlib

On the server side I use python zlib to compress a string as follows:

```
import zlib

s = '{"foo": "bar"}'
compress = zlib.compress(s)
print compress
```

The result of the previous code is the following

```
xœ«VJËÏW²RPJJ,Rª
```

On the client side I use [zlib.js](https://github.com/imaya/zlib.js/blob/develop/README.en.md) to decompress

```
var s = "xœ«VJËÏW²RPJJ,Rª"
var data = new Array(s.length);
for (i = 0, il = s.length; i < il; ++i) {
    data[i] = s.charCodeAt(i);
}
var inflate = new Zlib.Inflate(data);
```

I get the following error

```
zlib_and_gzip.min.js:1 Uncaught Error: invalid fcheck flag:28
    at new tb (zlib_and_gzip.min.js:48)
    at <anonymous>:1:15
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Double-check your encoding?  using a string might change byte-order or add unexpected bits?  You might consider using base64 for transmission to reduce such errors.

Comment: Definately an encoding problem. The string should be `var s = 'x\x9c\xabVJ\xcb\xcfW\xb2RPJJ,R\xaa\x05\x00 \x98\x04T'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was coding. in python I used base64 to encode.

```
>>> import zlib

>>> s = '{"foo": "bar"}'
>>> compress = zlib.compress(s)
>>> print compress.encode('base64')

>>> "eJyrVkrLz1eyUlBKSixSqgUAIJgEVA=="
```

On the client side:

```
var s = atob("eJyrVkrLz1eyUlBKSixSqgUAIJgEVA==");

var data = new Array(s.length);
for (i = 0, il = s.length; i < il; ++i) {
    data[i] = s.charCodeAt(i);
}

var inflate = new Zlib.Inflate(data);
var decompress = inflate.decompress();
var plain = new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(decompress);

plain 
'{"foo": "bar"}'
```

Thank you very much for the help